# Trouble Moving coffee script snippets into its own class within rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have been given the task to moved these coffee script code into a class

```
format = (icon) ->
  originalOption = icon.element
  '<i class="fa ' + $(originalOption).data('icon') + '"></i> ' + icon.text

$(document).ready ->
  $('.select2-fountawesome-icon').select2
    width: '100%'
    formatResult: format
```

Its a rails application and is working in `application.js.coffee`.

This is what I have so far in `scenario-page.js.coffee`

```
class @ScenarioPage
  constructor: ->
    @format()
    @enabledSelect2()

  format: (icon) ->
    originalOption = icon.element
    '<i class="fa ' + $(originalOption).data('icon') + '"></i> ' + icon.text

  enabledSelect2: () ->
    $('.select2-fountawesome-icon').select2
      width: '100%'
      formatResult: format
```

I created a class with a constructor that init the instance methods/properties. I dropped `document.ready` because coffee script loads after it anyway. The functions in the class should be defined correctly. I used try coffeescript to convert to js and it seems right. I am not sure what is wrong with my new class? The first snippet does work.

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors in your code :

```
class @ScenarioPage #<---- @ shouldn't be here
  constructor: ->
    @format() #<---- the icon param is missing, which will cause an error below
    @enabledSelect2()

  format: (icon) ->
    originalOption = icon.element
    '<i class="fa ' + $(originalOption).data('icon') + '"></i> ' + icon.text

  enabledSelect2: () ->
    $('.select2-fountawesome-icon').select2
      width: '100%'
      formatResult: format
```

And if I can add something that's how I would do :

```
class ScenarioPage
  constructor: ->

  format: (icon) ->
    originalOption = icon.element
    '<i class="fa ' + $(originalOption).data('icon') + '"></i> ' + icon.text

  enabledSelect2: () ->
    $('.select2-fountawesome-icon').select2
      width: '100%'
      formatResult: format

$(document).ready ->
  scenario = new ScenarioPage()
  scenario.enabledSelect2()
```

Now you would just have to call the format function when you want.
Don't hesitate to ask me if something seem unclear to you.

Regards,